# Eclipse: Is it possible to publish Javascript edits to an external Tomcat instance

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, web-applications, maven

I am converting an application from Flex to Javascript.  My workflow within Eclipse for Flex was to use Maven to start my Java web app in Tomcat and then have Eclipse configured to compile edited Actionscript files to a SWF and save it to my exploded WAR directory (that Maven/Cargo uses).

It worked very well for a long time allowing me to edit actionscript source code, flip over the browser, refresh the screen and see the changes.

I am new to Javascript however, and am struggling to get the same workflow up and running.  The part I don't understand is how to tell Eclipse that I would like my edited Javascript files to be written out to a particular directory (that contains the exploded WAR).  In my WAR project (a WTP dynamic web project) there is something that looks like a Javascript build path called "Javascript resources", but there is no output directory.

I would really like to continue to run Tomcat and Jetty via Maven if at all possible.  I realize I can do what I want via WTP (M2E-WTP), but would prefer to use Maven/Cargo.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible unless somehow you got eclipse to initiate a maven build every time you saved.

Comment: You can initiate anything you want inside eclipse build since you can run ant scripts (see my answer below)

Comment: However, I have to say that I find it strange to need to do such tweaks. I would prefer to make maven compile my swf which you can do by using a ant file (again) to pilot flex compiler ant task

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denis's suggestion to create custom builder is probably best solution if you want to continue using pure Maven/Cargo approach with Eclipse.

If you are deploying to an exploded war directory, then another similar idea would be to use a File Synchronization plugin. These will automatically copy modified files to configured folders. See:

- http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/
- https://wiki.onehippo.com/display/CMS7/Use+Filesync+Eclipse+plugin+for+faster+turn+around

### -------------

FWIW, I don't think Maven:Tomcat/Cargo plugins are ideal for real-time web development, especially on the frontend side of things. They are useful mainly for controlled deployments or bootstrapping a server without initial setup. My thoughts:

Eclipse WTP *used* to be great for real-time web development, but I stopped using it a few years back as it just got way too hard to make it work correctly in a Maven environment.  Fwiw, my preferred approach these days looks like this:

- Do not install or use Eclipse WTP.
- Use m2eclipse to integrate Maven with Eclipse.
- Use Maven to do clean builds and generate exploded WAR directory in target folder.
- Setup independent Tomcat server to load webapp from the exploded target folder.

  - I suspect the tomcat setup/startup could be integrated into Maven. It's not worth the extra complexity to me though.

Then, I configure JRebel (automatically via Maven) to handle java and web resource file changes. With this setup, I almost never have to redeploy or restart Tomcat. All changes (java, html, js, etc.) are seen immediately.

I *think* the same setup could be used without JRebel (for non-java files only) by configuring the web source folders as source folders in Eclipse with custom target output path being the corresponding directory in the exploded war directories. If that didn't work, then it would definitely work by using the custom builder or file synchronization solutions mentioned above.

Comment: This file sync plugin seems exactly like what I need.   Neither WTP nor JSDT have a "custom target output path" that I could find, else that would be my solution.  As it is, your file sync suggestion closely mirrors what I had with Flex...a "custom target output path" that I can point to my Maven/Cargo Tomcat exploded WAR.   JRebel has also been on my TODO list for some time...with this solution may have to accelerate that.

Comment: It worked flawlessly and took all of about 5 minutes to set up.  Thanks again.

Comment: Cool.  Regarding the custom output path, I uploaded a screenshot. You have to check "Allow output folders for source folders" to be able to adjust each source folder's corresponding output path independently. http://i.imgur.com/w59AV.png .

I'm not 100% positive that would work for your scenario though, and details might depend on Eclipse version.

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot.  I am aware of that capability, but it is part of the Java build path, the Javascript build path, and the web assembly descriptor have no such capability that I am aware of.  I do not think it is possible to override the Java build path with non-Java things, is it?

Comment: It's not intuitive, but source folders under "Java Build Path" are not specific to just Java files.  Here's another screenshot were I tested using an actual maven webapp folder's contents: http://i.imgur.com/wJNlY.png .  After configuring, I ran project...clean, and all files under the /webapp folder were copied to the target/webapp-root folder.  If you don't see that same functionality, then it might come down to Eclipse version (I'm using Indigo-SR1) or perhaps WTP is blocking that functionality. Be sure to check the included/excluded filters and possibly try setting included to "* * / * ".

Comment: OMG - It Just Works.  First let me say thank you.  Second let me rant for a bit.  I lost 5 days trying to configure WTP to work with Maven (I eventually got it working thanks to the new M2E-WTP project).  But all I had to do was add my Javascript folder to my Java build path!  How is a person supposed to know this?  They should just call it "Build Path" not "Java Build Path" -- its stuff like this that makes everyone think Eclipse is for Java development even when they say it isn't.  ARRGGGGG.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse introduces the concept of "**builder**" to build a project. It comes with hardcoded builders such as the java compiler or the war builder of WTP.

But eclipse also enable to setup your own Builder using **ant files** : on your project, right click the project properties, go to section Builders, click on the new button.

You can use arguments to your ant file and use variables defined in by eclipse to build them

Do not forget to fill the **refresh tab** if you want eclipse to by notified of the produced files.

Do not forget the fill the **Build options** tab, section "Specify working set of relevant resources" in order to have your builder called each time a source used by the build file is changed inside eclipse.

Also go to the "**targets**" tab to specify during which type of build phase your ant file is called and which target is called.

I knwo this solution may not be the best for you since your build process will be described more than once but it may help you achieve your goal.

Comment: I had no idea about this capability and really appreciate the suggestion!   However, if the file sync approach works, I think I'll flag that as the answer because it's simpler to set up than Ant which I don't know much about.